# How to use Google Identity Aware Proxy Sign In with allUser and Workspace access allowed?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-iap

I'm trying to set up a Google App Engine instance behind Identity Aware Proxy. I want to give access to allUsers and also restricted access to our Workspace.

I'm able to restrict the access by checking the JWT token but I can't work out how to prompt the sign in page IAP uses by default if access was only to the Workspace.

If allUser access is revoked IAP directs all users to a sign in page, I'd like to be able to direct users to this page.

How can I direct users to the sign in page while allowing allUser access - what is the url?

Comment: Do you mean in a single application, you want to a) Make every one sign-in before they can use the application b) For some pages in the same application, you then want to restrict people who sign in to only members of a specific group?

Comment: b) For some pages in the application I want to restrict access to only members of our workspace.

I am doing this already by checking the JWT token.

What I am unable to do is to show the default sign in page used by IAP to users who aren't signed in but want to.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [context-aware access](https://cloud.google.com/iap/docs/cloud-iap-context-aware-access-howto) (maybe restricting by hostname and path conditions)

Comment: The restricted access is not the problem - this is all working as I need. What I'm unable to do is direct users to the sign in page that IAP uses by default. If allUser access is revoked IAP directs all users to a sign in page, I'd like to be able to direct users to this page.

Answer (score 0):

When the `allUsers` principal is given `IAP-secured Web App User` access, you can use the following query parameter when requesting the IAP  to force the login screen:

`?gcp-iap-mode=FORCE_LOGIN`

> This enforces authentication to all incoming requests and redirects the request to target_domain after successful authentication.

Documented here: https://cloud.google.com/iap/docs/force-login